# How to place the image in right side inside of text field in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to place the image in right side inside  of text field in sencha touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by combining text field with label with corresponding image, here is an example:

```
 Ext.define("myapp.view.Places", {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'places',     
config: {    
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'location',
            labelWidth: '35%',                             
            flex: 4        
        },
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: '<span style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><img height="32px"  src="image.jpg"/></span>',
            padding: '6 0 0 0',
            flex: 1        
        }        
    ]        
}
```

});

Comment: Don't know how to format, I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

pass CSS like this, it will align your image in right side.

```
background: url(../icons/icon.png) no-repeat right;  /*your file path*/
```